# How to:CodeIgniter to create and call SoapClient in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap-client

I'm new to CodeIgniter and PHP.

Can someone tell me how to create a Soap client to call Soap server methods using CodeIgniter? Just any sample or an example.

Please help me, I want to learn how soap works in Codeigniter for my new web-app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using SoapClient is no different in CodeIgniter than it is using plain old PHP.

e.g. using SoapClient to load orders from Magento:

```
$client = new SoapClient($magento_server . "/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1");
$session = $client->login($magento_api_user, $magento_api_key);

$filters = array(
   'created_at' => array( '>' => $from_date),
   'created_at' => array( '<' => $to_date)
);

$orders = $client->salesOrderList($session, $filters);
```

PHP Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php